# How do I parse multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cheerio

I have been attempting to parse a sites table data into a json file, which I can do if I do each page one by one, but seeing as there are 415 pages that would take a while.

I have seen and read a lot of StackOverflow questions on this subject but I don't seem able to modify my script so that it;

1. Scrapes each page and extracts the 50 items with item IDS per page
2. Do so in a rate limited way so I don't negatively affect the server
3. The script waits until all requests are done so I can write each item + item id to a JSON file.

I believe you should be able to do this using request-promise and promise.all but I cannot figure it out.

**The actual scraping of the data is fine I just cannot make the code, scrape a page, then go to the next URL with a delay or pause inbetween requests.
Code below is the closest I have got, but I get the same results multiple times and I cannot slow the request rate down.**

Example of the page URLS:

1. http://test.com/itemlist/1
2. http://test.com/itemlist/2
3. http://test.com/itemlist/3 etc (upto 415)

   ```
   for (var i = 1; i <= noPages; i++) {
   urls.push({url: itemURL + i});
   console.log(itemURL + i);
   }

    Promise.map(urls, function(obj) {
    return rp(obj).then(function(body) {
   var $ = cheerio.load(body);
   //Some calculations again...
   rows = $('table tbody tr');
   $(rows).each(function(index, row) {
     var children = $(row).children();
     var itemName = children.eq(1).text().trim();
     var itemID = children.eq(2).text().trim();

     var itemObj = {
       "id" : itemID,
       "name" : itemName
     };

     itemArray.push(itemObj);
   });
   return itemArray;
     });
    },{concurrency : 1}).then(function(results) {
      console.log(results);
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      // access the result's body via results[i]
       //console.log(results[i]);
     }
    }, function(err) {
    // handle all your errors here
     console.log(err);
   });
   ```

Apologies for perhaps misunderstand node.js and its modules, I don't really use the language but I needed to scrape some data and I really don't like python.

Comment: have I got it right: you need request a page from the list, get its content, parse it somehow, wait for a while and request another page for parsing... and that's until you've fetched all the URLs in list.
is it correct?
if yes, making recursive promise should fit better than Promise.all because you will have just one active Promise in time

Comment: Hi, yes that's pretty much it, could you perhaps show me some pseudo code? Ive had to try learn a lot of concepts already for what was supposed to be a side project and its becoming a bit overwhelming. I will definitely need to return to this at a later date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you need requests to be run only one by one Promise.all() would not help.
Recursive promise (I'm not sure if it's correct naming) would.

```
function fetchAllPages(list) {
    if (!list || !list.length) return Promise. resolve(); // trivial exit
    var urlToFetch = list.pop();
    return fetchPage(urlToFetch).
        then(<wrapper that returns Promise will be resolved after delay >).
        then(function() {
            return fetchAllPages(list); // recursion! 
        });
}
```

This code still lacks error handling.
Also I believe it can become much more clear with async/await:

```
for(let url of urls) {
    await fetchAndProcess(url);
    await <wrapper around setTimeout>;
}
```

but you need to find /write your own implementation of `fetch()` and `setTimeout()` that are `async`

Comment: Just wanted to add a thank you, searching recursive promises really put me on the right path and showed me I was trying to use asynchronous functions synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

After input from @skyboyer suggesting using recursive promises I was lead to a GitHub Gist called [Sequential execution of Promises using reduce()](https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84)

Firstly I created my array of URLS

```
for (var i = 1; i <= noPages; i++) {
    //example urls[0] = "http://test.com/1"
    //example urls[1] = "http://test.com/2"
    urls.push(itemURL + i);
    console.log(itemURL + i);
}
```

Then

```
       var sequencePromise = urls.reduce(function(promise, url) {
         return promise.then(function(results) {
        //fetchIDsFromURL async function (it returns a promise in this case) 
         //when the promise resolves I have my page data
         return fetchIDsFromURL(url)
        .then(promiseWithDelay(9000))
        .then(itemArr => {
          results.push(itemArr);
          //calling return inside the .then method will make sure the data you want is passed onto the next
          return results;
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve([]));



// async
function fetchIDsFromURL(url)
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request(url, function(err,res, body){
      //console.log(body);
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      rows = $('table tbody tr');
      $(rows).each(function(index, row) {
        var children = $(row).children();
        var itemName = children.eq(1).text().trim();
        var itemID = children.eq(2).text().trim();
        var itemObj = {
          "id" : itemID,
          "name" : itemName
        };
        //push the 50 per page scraped items into an array and resolve with 
        //the array to send the data back from the promise
        itemArray.push(itemObj);
      });
      resolve(itemArray);
    });
 });
}

//returns a promise that resolves after the timeout
function promiseWithDelay(ms)
{
  let timeout =  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });

  return timeout;
}
```

Then finally call .then on the sequence of promises, the only issue I had with this was returning multiple arrays inside results with the same data in each, so since all data is the same in each array I just take the first one which has all my parsed items with IDs in it, then I wrote it to a JSON file.

```
  sequencePromise.then(function(results){
  var lastResult = results.length;
  console.log(results[0]);
  writeToFile(results[0]);
});
```

Comment: I see that is even better than recursive approach because you should not care about memory overhead(I'm not sure but believe small anonymous function that create recursion should create closure to all variables outside and that's would live(before marked as available for garbage collection) until ALL the pages are processed.